# prevent page-break when printing paragraph

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, page-break-inside

I want to print a page. However I notice that when a paragraph contains a little more text when printing it can break and be printed on the next page. I would like to avoid this, but it works not, probably due to the html structure:

```
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<label><span>Explanation expiration passed</span></label>
<p class="fake-form-control-disabled">some very large ipsum lorem text ....</p>
</div>
</div>
```

For the form-group class I have the following cdd definition:

```
.form-group {
        display: block;
        break-inside: avoid;
        margin-bottom: 15px;  
    }
```

It seems to work when I do not use the Bootstrap css grid e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group">  
<label><span>Explanation expiration passed</span></label>
<p class="fake-form-control-disabled">some very large ipsum lorem text ....</p>
</div>
```

What should I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the `break-inside` property onto the last-child-block level, in your case this is the `<p>` level, ex.

```
p {
    display: block;
    break-inside: avoid;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Alternatively, attach your `form-group` class to the column-level of the bootstrap grid, ex: `<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">`